# Is there a way to remove red underlines in colab cell?

Tags: google-colaboratory

[image: red underline image link]

A red underline appears in the cell almost every time I type a character, as seen in the image.

Is there a way to remove these red underlines?

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is a code diagnostics feature of google colab, so whenever you write something and it has a typo/syntax mistake then it starts showing red wavy line. In nutshell, if there is no typo mistake and still shows red wavy line just run your cell and it execute properly.

Step to remove red underline:

Step 1. Click on Tools.

Step 2. Click on Settings.

Step 3. Select Editor.

Step 4. In Code Diagnostics

```
          Select None
```